# fadein() not working after fadeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-hover

```
$("#slider").live("hover", function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $("#slider").delay(100).fadeIn(); 
    }
    else {
        $("#slider").delay(1200).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I used a slider in jQueryUI. What I would like to achieve is when the user hovers their mouse over the slider, it shows, and when the mouse is not hovered over it, it fades out. However, my case is after the first time of the fade out, the slider do not fade back in no matter where I put my mouse on that location of slider. How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: the slider has gone, there's nothing to `"hover"` over - you need to use `.fadeTo()` to just change the opacity without setting `display:none;` - http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo

Comment: Yes. I just tried fade To . This works as I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ahren's suggestions try this

```
$("#slider").hover( function( ) {
    $("#slider").fadeTo( 1000, 1 );
},
function( ) {
    $("#slider").fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqwaA/)

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution with `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers with `.animate()` method:

```
$("#slider").mouseover(function() {
    $("#slider").stop().animate({"opacity":0},500);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#slider").stop().animate({"opacity":1},500);
});
```